# Getting facebookexternalhit on URL being used during OAuth

Tags: facebook, oauth, web-crawler

I'm getting a `facebookexternalhit` UserAgent during our OAuth login redirect.

This is causing exceptions, because it tries using the FB OAuth token - luckily it already has been used by the user.

It's hitting an url like:

`/auth/fb/login-with-redirect?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%example.com%2Fnl&code=AQCwC2...YPe`

- Anyone else experiencing this?
- Is there any legit reason for FB to do this? Like checking for spam or whatever?
- I'm now sniffing out the `facebookexternal` hit useragent and just early return an empty page. Can this cause problems?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. Hundreds of daily requests to the login redirect by `facebookexternalhit`.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for letting me know. It helps to know that more people having the same issue and it might not be application related.